# Nest layouts programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have already added one layout to another using code, but in this particular case I can not get it to work for me. If you add them with an include in the xml files it works correctly, it tries to replicate in code the include of the .xml files. The layouts are these:

Parent layout (parent.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--<include layout="@layout/child_1" /> this work fine -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

First child (child_1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/child_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_1_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- First row: header -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_row"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    ... />

                <TextView
                    ... />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Second row: ... -->
            <!-- <include layout="@layout/child_2" />  this work fine  -->
            include child_2 programmatically here. This does not work, 

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/child_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the java code with which I try to replicate the previous includes:

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent));

LinearLayout child_1 = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_1, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_1));

LinearLayout child_1_2 = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_1, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_1_2));

LinearLayout child_2 = (LinearLayout) lyInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_2, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.child_2));

child_1_2.addView(child_2);
parent.addView(child_1);
```

The parent layout correctly adds to child_1, but child_1 does not show child_2.

Comment: This is quite confusing.  I'm sure it's a simple error somewhere.  You should try to be a clear as humanly possible.  "it tries to replicate in code " what is *it* ?  Why did you say this?

Comment: And you are trying EITHER one method OR the other, and not BOTH, correct?

Comment: Child_1 and child 1_2 are the same thing, correct?

Comment: is it simply that the last line should say 'parent.add(child_1_2);'  NOT 'parent.add(child_1);' ??

Comment: With "it tries to replicate in code" it tried to say that it needed to do the same in java that already done in xml.

Comment: Child_1 and child_1_2 are not at all the same thing as can be seen in the xml code.

Comment: "is it simply that the last line should say..." I do not understand what this means.

Comment: The last line is correct as it was in the question. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 1 layout need to inflat here: **child_2**.

and **child_1_2** should define base on **child_1** like this

```
LinearLayout child_1_2 = child_1.findViewById(R.id.child_1_2);
```

Comment: Thank you! Effectively, the child_1_2 must be inflated as you indicate. On the other hand, the code to nest the layouts is the following (only two lines):

child_1_2.addView (child_2);
parent.addView (child_1);

Thank you very much for your responses!